# Is there any way to make a iOS app available for beta-testing (adhoc app) without using the tester UUID

Tags: ios, testing, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to make my app available for the testers without adding their UUIDs to the distribution profile. Is there any way to achieve this. I know about Enterprise distribution but my app will eventually be uploaded to AppStore.
So I also want to know is it possible to use same Apple ID for both Enterprise App and App Store app.

Thank you

Comment: I believe that in itunes connect you can send them a beta using test flight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UDID is no longer required. The focus is on test users rather than device. A single user may have multiple devices on which the beta app may be installed.**

> You can enable up to 25 users from your iTunes Connect team to be
>   internal testers and up to 1000 users to be external testers. External
>   testers do not need to be in your organisation; you can invite any
>   user with an email address to become one of your external testers.

reference from below link :
https://subodhnpushpak.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/deploying-ios-apps-without-udid-to-beta-testers-using-testflight-beta-testing/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the new Testflight feature on the developer portal:  https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

You have two options when using this.  For internal testing anyone who is tied to your account can test it.  For external testing your app has to go through the approval process, and you can give out an email that will allow them to test it, or put their email in and it will send out an invitation to that person to install the app.  Any updates to the app have to be approved before it can go to external testers.